# Ubuntu other Locations not showing windows SSD data in acer

Tags: 20.04

My computer has a 256GB SSD and a 1TB HDD. I have divided the hard drive into two 500GB partitions to install Ubuntu onto one of them. Ubuntu can see the Windows partition on the hard drive, but not the SSD:

[image]

How can I see the Windows partitions on both the hard drive and the SSD?

Comment: What type of SSD? SATA? M.2? PCIe?

Comment: If you open the "Disks" application, do you see both your SSD and hard drive? 

Comment: Dubbelclick on ```computer``` (screenshot) , that should be the the SSD.

Comment: No I have checked the disks ,it is not showing my SSD data